# How to quickly find all grid cells covered by a geometric region?

Tags: graphics, regions

I'm trying to compute a complete set of unit grid cells ("pixels") which a geometric region covers at least partially. I have constructed a method that produces correct results:

```
With[{reg = Polygon@RandomReal[{0, 10}, {3, 2}]}, 
 Graphics[{reg, Blue, Opacity[1/2], 
   Rectangle[{x, y}] /. 
    Quiet@Solve[
      Resolve[Exists[{xp, yp}, 
        RegionMember[RegionIntersection[Rectangle[{x, y}], reg], {xp, yp}]], 
       Reals], {x, y}, Integers]}]]
```

[image]

The problem with this implementation is that it's absurdly slow - producing this result takes several seconds for just a small triangle.

How correct results (preferably for arbitrary regions) could be produced more efficiently? Before suggesting use of `Rasterize`, please note that non-antialised `Rasterize` does not always produce identical results with code above.

Comment: Not sure if [this](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1995/Dec/msg00401.html) is what you are looking for, but maybe it'll be useful in one way or another. Or maybe not.

Comment: @corey979 I fear it's a solution to a different problem... :o

Comment: Is your region always a polygon or do you need to work with more general region objects?

Comment: @george2079 I would fancy a solution which would work at least for all (finite) semialgebraic sets, but even non-self-intersecting polygons are a start.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that input is a list of points-vertices of a polygon on 2d plane plus their connectivity? Disconnected sets and non convex sets are also allowed?

Comment: @yarchik Disconnected sets and non-convex sets should also be allowed (although maybe one could limit the task to semialgebraic sets to prevent problem getting too hairy...). My original question arose from the fact that what was the "obvious" general purpose solution back in the v11.0 was so awfully slow in practice even for the simplest primitives. The problem statement itself is pretty much described by the `Exists` statement above.

Answer (score 11):

This may seem a bit crude but it should be fast and robust - 
finely discretize the region and look for the mesh vertices to be in cells:

```
r = Polygon@RandomReal[{0, 10}, {3, 2}]
gridorigin = Floor[{Min[r[[1, All, 1]]], Min[r[[1, All, 2]]]}];
gridspace = {1, 1};
cc = Union[(({Round[#[[1]], gridspace[[1]]], 
           Round[#[[2]], gridspace[[2]]]} + gridorigin + 
          gridspace/2) &@ (# - gridorigin - gridspace/2) ) & /@ 
    MeshCoordinates[DiscretizeRegion[r, MaxCellMeasure -> .01]]];
RegionPlot[r, PlotRange -> All, 
 Prolog -> {{FaceForm[Blue], 
    Rectangle[# - gridspace/2, # + gridspace/2] & /@ cc},
   Line[{gridorigin + {#, 0}, gridorigin + {#, 10}}] & /@ 
    Range[0, 8, gridspace[[1]]],
   Line[{gridorigin + {0, #}, gridorigin + {10, #}}] & /@ 
    Range[0, 8, gridspace[[2]]]} , AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

it should work with anything that `DiscritizeRegion` can handle:

```
r = ImplicitRegion[x^2 - y^2 <= 1 || x^2 + y^2 == 4, {x, y}];
gridorigin = {-5, -5};
gridspace = {.25, .5};
cc = Union[(({Round[#[[1]], gridspace[[1]]], 
           Round[#[[2]], gridspace[[2]]]} + gridorigin + 
          gridspace/2) &@ (# - gridorigin - gridspace/2) ) & /@ 
    MeshCoordinates[
     DiscretizeRegion[r, {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}, MaxCellMeasure -> .01]]];
RegionPlot[r, PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}, 
 Prolog -> {{FaceForm[Blue], 
    Rectangle[# - gridspace/2, # + gridspace/2] & /@ cc},
   Line[{gridorigin + {#, 0}, gridorigin + {#, 10}}] & /@ 
    Range[0, 10, gridspace[[1]]],
   Line[{gridorigin + {0, #}, gridorigin + {10, #}}] & /@ 
    Range[0, 10, gridspace[[2]]]} , AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

note the region here includes an open circle, so the "holes" are correct.
here are the mesh vertices:

[image]

Comment: I was trying to use `MinValue` with `ManhattanDistance`, which amounts to the same thing, but this is far and away faster. +1

Comment: Does your figure 2 show the limitation of a numerical method (potential inaccuracy) by the asymmetry of the blue highlighting in the centre? Numerical routes are likely the fastest though if one is not concerned with small chances of small errors.

Comment: @Quantum_Oli, yes in the second example the region precisely mathematically hits a grid line at a tangent point so its a round off issue whether that adjacent box gets counted or not.  You might discard mesh points that fall within some tolerance of the grid lines to remedy that issue.

Answer (score 9):

A slightly quicker method, no time to explain atm. It might be sped up by reworking the `Area[RegionIntersection[...]]` bit.

```
With[{reg = Polygon@RandomReal[{0, 10}, {3, 2}]},
 {{xMin, xMax}, {yMin, yMax}} = Floor[MinMax /@ Transpose@reg[[1]]];
 Graphics[{reg, Blue, Opacity[1/2], 
  Select[Flatten[
     Table[Rectangle[{x, y}, {x + 1, y + 1}], {x, xMin, xMax}, {y, yMin, yMax}]],
    Area[RegionIntersection[reg, #]] != 0 &]}]]
```

Comment: `MinMax /@ Transpose@reg[[1]]` could be replaced with more general-purpose `RegionBounds[reg]`, BTW.

Comment: +1 Beat me to it.  You can replace `Rectangle[{x,y}, {x+1, y+1}]` with `Rectangle[{x,y}]`.  This is sometimes faster than the OP code, but sometimes not.  Here's [my version](http://pastebin.com/raw/CSNHgKFB), and two examples, one where the `Select` version is faster, and one where the `Resolve` version is faster.

Comment: It would seem it can be faster to check for nonzero area (or more specifically, existence of points belonging to the region) by using `Resolve`-`Exists` style test than using `Area` (which computes an useless value). Still not very fast, I'd assume this problem to be resolved at least for polygons with millisecond-level timing.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback guys, always learning! It looks like @kirma's approach below combining this rough approach but cleverly pre-evaluating the `Select` predicate is much faster than this (and the fastest non-discretizing approach so far).

Answer (score 6):

This answer combines my own code from the question and the idea in @Quantum_Oli's answer. It is already quite much faster than either, at least for polygons:

```
With[{reg = Polygon@RandomReal[{0, 10}, {3, 2}]},
 Graphics[{reg, Blue, Opacity[1/2],
   Rectangle /@ 
    Select[Flatten[CoordinateBoundsArray@Floor@RegionBounds@reg, 1],
     Apply[
      Evaluate[
        Resolve[Exists[{xp, yp}, 
          RegionMember[
           RegionIntersection[Rectangle[{#1, #2}], reg], {xp, yp}]], 
         Reals]] &]]}]]
```

Comment: One can also check whether `RegionDimension[...] > -Infinity`, but I don't know if that's faster or slower than the `Resolve[Exists[...]]` method.

Comment: @Rahul Hmm, didn't know, or maybe just remember that one!

Comment: @Rahul Now I remember why I don't use it. `RegionDimension` doesn't evaluate for parametric regions, thus making pre-evaluation of `Select` predicate impossible. Probably it is better for more complicated regions, while my answer is better for simpler ones - at least triangles.

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty fast, but one probably needs to be careful with [`MaxCellMeasure`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxCellMeasure.html).  I use [`DensityHistogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityHistogram.html) of the [`MeshCoordinates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshCoordinates.html) to pull out the squares.

```
Block[{reg = Polygon@RandomReal[{0, 10}, {3, 2}], pix}, 
 pix = Cases[
   DensityHistogram[
     MeshCoordinates[
      TriangulateMesh[DiscretizeGraphics[reg], 
       MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01]], {{1}, {1}}, 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"] // 
    InputForm, _Rectangle, \[Infinity]];
 Graphics[{Opacity[0.5, Blue], EdgeForm[Black], pix, reg}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

A method based on `RegionDilation` introduced in v12.3:

```
With[{reg = Polygon@RandomReal[{0, 10}, {3, 2}]}, 
 Graphics[{reg, Blue, Opacity[1/2], Rectangle /@
   Select[Flatten[CoordinateBoundsArray@Floor@RegionBounds@reg, 1],
     RegionMember[RegionDilation[reg, Rectangle[{-1, -1}]]]]}]]
```

This method is several hundred times faster for triangles than my original method on the question.

Another method based on computing a symbolic selection function based on `RegionDisjoint` (introduced in v11.1). This is about ten times slower for triangles than the method above, but still faster than the original:

```
With[{reg = Polygon@RandomReal[{0, 10}, {3, 2}]}, 
 Graphics[{reg, Blue, Opacity[1/2], Rectangle /@
    Select[Flatten[CoordinateBoundsArray@Floor@RegionBounds@reg, 1],
     Apply@
      Function[{x, y}, Evaluate[! RegionDisjoint[reg, Rectangle[{x, y}]]]]]}]]
```

These methods are usable on other regions too, say

```
reg = Annulus[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2], Accumulate@RandomReal[{2, 5}, 2]]
```

[image]